# Extract report from Qlikview desktop_with python

Tags: python, nonetype, qlikview

the part of the script with the error looks like this :

ActiveDoc = qvapp.OpenDoc(doc) # Open QlikView application
print('Extracting:', qv_object_id)
ActiveDoc.GetSheetObject(qv_object_id).Export(temp_path + 'temp.txt','\t') # Export object's data to temporary file
df = pd.read_csv(temp_path + 'temp.txt', sep='\t' ,parse_dates=[0]) # Read previously exported data into Pandas
print('Saving:', file_path)
df.to_excel(file_path,sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, engine='openpyxl') # Save data to its final destination

print('Extraction finished.')

qvapp.Quit()

while the error is this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users...\Desktop\test2.py", line 50, in 
ActiveDoc.GetSheetObject(qv_object_id).Export(temp_path + 'temp.txt','\t') # Export object's data to temporary file
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Export'